# why doesn't proc_get_status() show me a process has crashed?

Tags: php

This PHP command-line script runs another script with **proc_open()**:

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w")
);
$crash = proc_open('php crash.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
$status = proc_get_status($crash);
print_r($status);
```

The inner script just crashes deliberately:

```
<?php
crash();
```

I would expect **proc_get_status()** to tell me the process is no longer running, and has an exit code of 255.

However, this is the output:

```
Array
(
    [command] => php crash.php
    [pid] => 78769
    [running] => 1
    [signaled] =>
    [stopped] =>
    [exitcode] => -1
    [termsig] => 0
    [stopsig] => 0
)
```

Why does the status still show it as running?

(I can't use proc_close() in my real use case, as I specifically want to pass multiple things to the inner script and see which one causes it to crash.)

Comment: The way concurrency works is that the child process will only start when the creating process gives up control. This happens when the OS decides to context switch (which is not instantly) or when the process gives up control by going into a suspended state via e.g. a sleep.

Answer (score 6):

I have modified your code to add while-loop for watching `running` value returned by `proc_get_status`

```
<?php
$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"),
   1 => array("pipe", "w")
);
$crash = proc_open('php crash.php', $descriptorspec, $pipes);
while (true) {
    $status = proc_get_status($crash);
    print_r($status);
    sleep(1);
}
```

Run above code will output two array side by side, the second one should show `running` as `false` as well, It is enough for 1 seconds delay to show the problem of race condition.

```
$ php modified_demo.php
Array
(
    [command] => php crash.php
    [pid] => 32575
    [running] => 1
    [signaled] =>
    [stopped] =>
    [exitcode] => -1
    [termsig] => 0
    [stopsig] => 0
)
Array
(
    [command] => php crash.php
    [pid] => 32575
    [running] =>
    [signaled] =>
    [stopped] =>
    [exitcode] => 1
    [termsig] => 0
    [stopsig] => 0
)
^C
```